# How can i crop image using C# in asp webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how i can crop image on webpage 
like facebook or linkedin sites?

and how i can call c# method in asp when mouse select area of image?

Note: not desktop

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried anything to solve your problem first? Read [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I would recommend not trying to call C# from ASP classic, but use ASP.NET.

Comment: @GáborBakos: I'd go further and guess that this question is mis-tagged, because as far as I know, you *can't* use C# in ASP classic.

Comment: i tried but by desktop application not asp page